# android - when to do GCM registration

Tags: android, django, client, google-cloud-messaging, registration

I have a android client app, a server side in django and now I am adding push notifications with GCM.
In my app I have users that login/logout, so I will have a table in my database with devices ids coupled with users, so that every time I want to notification a user, I will lookup its device id and send the notification.

*my question is*:

> When is best to register the Device to the GCM?
>
> When to add the Device to my Server side database?

In the *Google Docs* it says you should do it once, when the app is installed.

Because I have users in my app, and I want to couple a user with a device in the database, when the app is installed there still isn't a user to associate the Device with.

After the user installs the app, he can register, login and so on.

> So when you think is best to register the Device to the GCM **and** to my server side?
>
> Should it be with a user or only associate it later?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be:

1. Register the device immediately after the first execution
2. Save device id somewhere accessible anytime by the app
3. Couple the id with user details after registration

With this approach you will be able to handle issues if something goes wrong with the registration process and send a notification to the device even if the user is not registered.

**EDIT:**

4. You should also implement a strategy to check on a regular basis if the association between the user and the device is still valid or needs to be updated